# I want to await the return of a lambda function and return the result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Considering the following code sample,

```
public XYZ GetSomething(string pluginId, string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        var plugin = (PluginType)_pluginManager.GetPlugin(pluginId, false);

        plugin.RegisterCallback(result =>
        {
            //return this object instance of type XYZ
            return result;
        });

        plugin.RequestData(arg1, arg2);

        return null;
    }
```

How can I make this method async and await the result of the lambda function and return the result without turning this method into a blocking method? `RequestData` of `plugin` is non-blocking and I cannot change it. `result` is eventually returned and is an object instance not wrapped in any task.

How can I await the result in the lambda function and then return the result?

**Edit:**
`RequestData` completes very quickly. It supposedly requests data from a remote server and then invokes the callback once such data is returned which can take between seconds and minutes.

Comment: You can mark a lambda expression async by putting "async" keyword just before its argument list, but I doubt RegisterCallback accepts async delegates as parameter.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineJacob thats not much use without an await somewhere

Comment: @TimRutter Obviously, that's what I meant but RegisterCallback will not accept async delegates which returns a Task<T> by the await.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create something that you can use with `async await` you have to create a `Task`. So your `GetSomething()` method has to return `Task<XYZ>`. Then in the next step it depends on how your `.RequestData()` method works. Does it block or not? Due to the architecture about first register a callback, I would think that `.RequestData()` returns immediately and when it is done it calls the callback. To wrap these things up within your `GetSomething()` method you could use a `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting");
    Start();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async Task Start()
{
    var result = await GetSometing("abc", "def", "ghi");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}


public static Task<int> GetSometing(string pluginId, string arg1, string arg2)
{
    var plugin = new PluginMock();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    plugin.RegisterCallback(result =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(result);
    });

    plugin.RequestData(arg1, arg2);

    return tcs.Task;
}

public class PluginMock
{
    private Action<int> _callback;

    public void RegisterCallback(Action<int> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void RequestData(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _callback(42);
        });

        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `RequestData` does not block. I edited my question and added that info. It returns very quickly, but the invocation of the callback can take seconds to minutes...

Comment: @MattWolf He acknowledged this in his answer. Pretty solid, but a bit tiedous to work with, considering it creates a new thread.

Comment: It doesn't create a new Thread. That just the `PluginMock` to mimic some asynchronous stuff happening in the plugin. All the user has to do is within the `GetSomething()` method.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks a lot, this really helps and answers my question.